# How to turn off Turbo Boost temporarily?

Tags: performance, testing

In our application we have many versions of the same routine optimized for different kind of processor architectures. During install we run performance tests and select the best version of routine.

Latest processors can boost their frequencies if few cores are in use, so sometimes our tests peeking wrong version of routine. Is there some way to temporarily turn off Turbo Boost?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this ? I'd like to be able to turn off Turbo Boost on a Mac, so that I can do reliable benchmarking during code optimisation etc. I don't even mind if I have to reboot to achieve this, but it doesn't seem possible, unlike on a PC, where you can do it via a BIOS setting.

Comment: @Paul R: nope. I spent two days googling, and decided to leave it as it is.

Comment: it seems that the best you can do at the moment is disable it in the BIOS if you have PC hardware, but on a Mac you're out of luck. There does seem to be a possibility of hacking rEFITt to do it, but I don't have time to investigate this just now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the opcode for enabling/disabling turbo boost directly, but apparently it's possible because [TMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/tmonitor.php) - which is a Windows application - can do it at runtime.

Comment: Nice utility, but Turbo Boost toggle doesn't do the work, at least on my laptop.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that TMonitor can toggle Turbo Boost in Windows?

Answer (score 2):

There are MSR registers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-specific_register) in Intel CPUs to disable/enable per-core turbo boost. In linux, there are `msr-tools` package which allow root to read/write to MSR registers. There are two posts about Turbo Boost disabling/enabling in Linux:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu "Disabling Intel Turbo Boost in ubuntu", answer by Maythux from 2015

http://luisjdominguezp.tumblr.com/post/19610447111/disabling-turbo-boost-in-linux
Disabling Turbo Boost in Linux, Luis J. Dominguez P, 2012-2013; Sandy Bridge - "38th bit of the 0x1a0 register."

http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2014/11/a-script-to-turn-off-intel-cpu-turbo.html

And there is kext for OSX to do the same: [Disable Turbo Boost on Core i7 Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178584/disable-turbo-boost-on-core-i7-mac)

Answer (score -1):

In windows OS you can add the following reg key.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\be337238-0d82-4146-a960-4f3749d470c7]
"Attributes"=dword:00000002
```

Then in advanced power settings you will get new option that allows you turning off turbo boost.
[image]